# The content of adapter has changed but listview did not receive a notification

Tags: android

I have research a lot on this but nothing satisfy me .Everyone give me the a solution put the **adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()** in runOnUiThread which i have already done bit didi not give me the solution. 
**My Code is below**
public class FragmentActivity3 extends Fragment {

```
// Hashmap for ListView
ArrayList<Item> imageArry = new ArrayList<Item>();
CustomQuoteAdapter adapter;
String jsonstring;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment_activity1, container,false);
    jsonstring=JsonClass.readData();
    Log.d("JSon String ",jsonstring);
    new GetQuotesInfo().execute();
    adapter = new CustomQuoteAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list, imageArry);
    ListView dataList = (ListView) rootView. findViewById(R.id.list);
    dataList.setAdapter(adapter);
    return rootView;
}

//Async Task to load  data
    class GetQuotesInfo extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        int count;
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                JSONArray jsonarr=new JSONArray(Globals.jsonText);
                count=jsonarr.length();
                for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
                {
                    HashMap<String, String> quoteinfo = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    String author="";
                    Log.d("Json","Reading");
                    JSONObject jsonobj=jsonarr.getJSONObject(i);
                    String name=jsonobj.getString("name");
                    quoteinfo.put("name", name);
                    JSONArray jarr=jsonobj.getJSONArray("quotes");
                    String[] myarr=new String[jarr.length()];
                    String[] myarr1=new String[jarr.length()];
                    for(int j=0;j<jarr.length();j++)
                    {


                        JSONObject jobj=jarr.getJSONObject(j);
                        author=jobj.getString("author");
                        String text=jobj.getString("text");
                        Log.d("Author ",author);
                        Log.d("Text ",text);
                        myarr[j]=text;
                        myarr1[j]=author;
                    }

                    imageArry.add(new Item(name,myarr1, myarr));

                }

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

        }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                public void run() {
                   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        }

    }
```

}

**My Adapter class is below**

```
public class CustomQuoteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {
    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    LinearLayout linearMain;
    ArrayList<Item> data = new ArrayList<Item>();

    public CustomQuoteAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
            ArrayList<Item> data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((FragmentActivity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            linearMain = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.lineraMain);
            Item myImage = data.get(position);
            TextView txtview=new TextView(context);
            String heading=myImage.heading;
            txtview.setText(heading);
            txtview.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            txtview.setTextSize(20);
            linearMain.addView(txtview);

            for (int j = 0; j < myImage.getName().length; j++) {
                TextView label1 = new TextView(context);
                label1.setText(myImage.author[j]);
                linearMain.addView(label1);
                TextView label2 = new TextView(context);
                label2.setText(myImage.name[j]);
                linearMain.addView(label2);
            }
//          ImageView image = new ImageView(context);
//          int outImage = myImage.image;
//          image.setImageResource(outImage);
//          linearMain.addView(image);
        }

        return row;

    }

}
```

**Can anyone give me the solution to resolve my error**

Comment: remove the runOnUIthread from your asynctask its not needed and use ex.printStackTrace() in your json. Invalid json could be the cause

Comment: you should avoid using notifyDataSetChanged in onPostExecute. Prefer to create a callback method that is dedicated to update your adapter. Also getActivity() can be null in some cases be carefull when using it.

Answer (score 0):

`onPostExecute()` is automatically called on the UI thread, so you don't need the `runOnUIThread()`

Have you checked to make sure the data in your list is actually changing?  Also I didn't go through the logic of your entire adapter, but this line looks like there's a typo.  I'm guessing your IDE would have caught it if that typo weren't also in your resources file too though
`linearMain = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.lineraMain);`
Not sure if that typo `R.id.lineraMain` is causing you problems.